# How to create a spinner with image buttons?

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-button

I wanted to create a drop down menu on clicking an image button.Do i need to create a spinner for this?Could you please tell me how to create a drop down menu using spinner?

Answer (score 2):

Add this attribute in the button in the xml file

```
 android:background="@android:drawable/btn_dropdown"
```

and you get a drop down image in the button and in the click of the button you can perform your operation

Answer (score 1):

USE BELOW GIVEN CODE IN YOUR PROJECT :

You need to take one button and set any image as its background.Then on click of the button call Spinner.performClick() to open the spinner.

Below is code to implement the same thing. In xml file:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/font"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="@drawable/textsel" /> 

 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spin"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:dropDownHorizontalOffset="0dp"
    android:dropDownVerticalOffset="20dp"
    android:dropDownWidth="500dp"
    android:paddingTop="2sp"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown" >
</Spinner>
```

In Java class:

```
  Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spin);

  Button typetext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.font);      


  typetext.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        spin.performClick();

    }
});
```

You can ask if you have any further queries!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://stephenpengilley.blogspot.in/2013/01/android-custom-spinner-tutorial.html) is an example of creating custom spinner. Also you can open an AlertDialog with with single choice selection. It is similar to drop down menu [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660887/android-dialog-single-choice-get-radio-selected) is an example.

Comment: How to design an image button in such a way that when i click the image button it as to list some info?

Answer (score 0):

Better use list view , making it look like a drop down.