# Android: simple_list_item_single_choice is not working with ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

In my ListView i want single selection to delete the item. For that i am using simple_list_item_single_choice with ArrayAdapter. It show me the single choice option in my ListView. But i am not able to click on that checkbox.

Here is my code:

```
       ArrayList array_list_title = mydb.getTitle();
    System.out.println(array_list_title);

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =      
              new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, array_list_title);
    listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6849534/1318946

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to use [ListView.setChoiceMode(int mode)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setChoiceMode(int)). Like

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE); // Enables multiple selection
```

or

```
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE); // Enables single selection
```

to enable checkboxes.

---

So your code will be like

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter =      
              new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, array_list_title);
listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```