# how to get json array into dialog fragment

Tags: java, android

I have an issue in a `dailog` fragment. I want to get a `json` array into the `dailog` fragment, but I don't know how to do it, here is what am trying. Any suggetion's ?

```
public class MyAlertSortDialogFragmentIndividual extends DialogFragment {
public static final String DATA = "items";
public static final String SELECTED = "selected";
CharSequence[] cs;
ArrayList<User> transactionList = new ArrayList<>();
List <User> users;
String s;
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     users=new ArrayList<>();
    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
    dialog.setTitle("Sort By");
    dialog.setPositiveButton("Cancel", new PositiveButtonClickListener());
    bundle.putSerializable("key", transactionList);

    String str = bundle.getString("str");

    users = new Gson().fromJson(str,ArrayList.class);


    return dialog.create();
}
class PositiveButtonClickListener implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        dialog.dismiss();

    }
}

DialogInterface.OnClickListener selectItemListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        // process
        //which means position

        dialog.dismiss();
    }
};
```

how should I get the data from model class.

Comment: show me your str value String str = bundle.getString("str"); this one

Comment: users = new Gson().fromJson(str,ArrayList.class);      here in this line you have to set the class name which has the instance in this str   ...................herer ,ArrayList.class wrong value

Comment: also post code where you send this str value to MyAlertSortDialogFragmentIndividual this fragment

Comment: actually my problem is that i need array list of json data into dialog box and i did not found any suitable example for the same.

Comment: yes same thing i told you just show me tha str value

Comment: "Users": [
        {
            "username": "ashish",
            "userid": "97"
        }
    ]

Answer (score 1):

```
public class NewItem {

private String name;
private String age;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
 }
}
```

If this is your model class then to get data:

```
 String userName,age;
 for (NewItem item : users) {
      if(item.getName().equals(REQUIRED_USERNAME)){
         userName = item.getName();
         age = item.getAge();
      }
  }
```

Comment: you can create the constructor and pass the parameter of array

Comment: i want to json array list data into dialog fragment with single choice

Comment: what you mean by single choice?Your users list wil contain all user names..You have to choose  one?

Comment: yes exactly my requirement like that can you suggest me how to do?

Comment: But you need to know whch user you want right.See the updated code.You should do like that.

Comment: i passed shared prefrences value for first user after clicked the user i want to user list can you show me the code where you wright on that.

Comment: see the updated code.Instead of REQUIRED_USERNAME your should pass the name from the preferences and your problem is solved.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.lang.Iterable.iterator()' on a null object reference

Comment: Then users must be null

Answer (score 0):

First the json format you get is not valid json format send json format like

```
 {
    "Users": [
        {
            "username": "ashish",
            "userid": "97"
        }
    ]
}
```

not like -"Users": [ { "username": "ashish", "userid": "97" } ]

after that map this into class

```
public class UsersResponce implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("Users")
    @Expose
    private List<User> users = null;

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public class User  implements Serializable{

        @SerializedName("username")
        @Expose
        private String username;
        @SerializedName("userid")
        @Expose
        private String userid;

        public String getUsername() {
            return username;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username) {
            this.username = username;
        }

        public String getUserid() {
            return userid;
        }

        public void setUserid(String userid) {
            this.userid = userid;
        }

    }
}
```

Than pass that str value and get Pojo Class like

```
UsersResponce users = new Gson().fromJson(str,UsersResponce.class);
if(null!=UsersResponce){
   List<User> usersList =UsersResponce.getUsers();
   if(null!=usersList&&usersList.size()>0){
     for (User item : usersList) {
      if(item.getUserid().equals(CURRENT_LOGIN_USERID)){
         //than set your adapter selcted here 
      }
     }
   }
}
```

For single choice adapter refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6849534/4741746)